# Error code from panel cannont find module ./config

Tags: discord.js

Error: Cannot find module './config.js'
Require stack:

- /home/container/commands/global.js
- /home/container/index.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object. (/home/container/commands/global.js:3:16)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/home/container/commands/global.js', '/home/container/index.js' ]

Anyone know a fix?

Expecting for the cmd to show and pterodactyl panel not to error and restart

Comment: Without code, we can't help to fix anything..
But in general, your error say that node cannot find './config.js' so check if you have this file and the path